# React Native Linking - How to properly get url?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use `Linking` component in `react-native` . I finished setting the AppDelegate part for iOS, however, when I try to get the initialUrl by running the code below in `componentDidMount()`, I always get a `null` value in the url. Is there something I missed? How can I fix this?

```
Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
      console.log('was here')
      console.log(url)
      if (url) {
        Linking.openURL(url)
        console.log('egul')
        console.log(url)
      }
    }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow all the instructions on this page:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking

There are necessary items you need to do in the native code, not just adding the linking code that's shown directly after the "Handling Deep links".

Answer (score 0):

For those who're coming here, you need to disable debugger. You can't `console log(url)`. To check if you code is working set the url in the state and render it in your app.

```
state={
      url:''
}

componentDidMount(){
Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
  if (url) {
    this.setState({url})
  }
}).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err))
}

render(){
return(
   <View>
      <Text>
         {this.state.url}
      </Text>
   </View>
)}
```